# Calling files inside PHAR

Tags: php, package, require, phar

I know that you can call files using require 'phar://pharname.phar/path/to/file.php'; but what about when both files are in the same PHAR? I tried using require 'path/to/file.php'; but that throws an error which makes sense since the file is in the packaged phar and not in the directory it's in.

Comment: There is [`Phar::interceptFileFuncs`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.interceptfilefuncs.php) for accessing relative paths within one.

Comment: I still seem to have the same issue.  Is there another way around this?

Comment: "Having an issue" and having some concrete code to show are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

A phar file has an [alias](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.setalias.php) that can be used to address files inside the archive:

Inside a phar file with the alias `foo.phar` you can do

```
include 'phar://foo.phar/path/to/file.php';
```

to include a file from the same archive. See the [Phar::__construct() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.construct.php) for another example.